# Recursively copying specific directories

Tags: copy

I was wondering if it's possible to copy multiple specific directories recursively at once.

I know I can copy all sub-directories like so

```
cp -rp root/pass/dir/* root/other/dir/
```

But I'm wondering if I can recursively copy specific directories like with files

```
cp -p root/pass/dir/subdir/file{1,2,3}.php root/other/dir/
```

Lets say, in *dir* there are sub-directories *subdir1*, *subdir2*, *subdir3*.

Can I copy them recursively in the same way? e.g.

```
cp -rp root/pass/dir/subdir{1,2}/ root/other/dir/
```

Comment: Have you tried ?
All three examples you provide are missing a destination, I think.

Comment: No, company doesn't like me "trying" stuff on their servers. And I'll add a dest but not really about that...

Comment: You can simply test this things on some empty directories; And something like `cp -rp /path/dir/{1,2} /dest/paty` works fine.

Comment: @Ravexina any documentation? I really haven't been able to find anything about it.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work. 
If company don't like you testing in production, they of course provide a test-system ? Or you can test in a vm on ypur pc, for instance in VirtualBox.